# How to affect current month automatically to a picker ? IONIC 4

Tags: date, ionic-framework, default, picker

I'm working under Ionic 4.

I'm developping an app that allows a firm to visualize and keep up to date well being indicator of their services. In order to do so, managers are giving a forecast of how their service is doing. They have to do that once a month.

I want to set the current month by default in the picker, for better UI experience and economy of clicks, but i'm not able to find a solution.

For now, the picker only displays the current month, but the user still have to click and select it.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try with below solution :

home.page.html

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>MMMM</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM" [value]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

</ion-content>
```

home.page.ts

```
export class HomePage {
  myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();
  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {}

}
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: First of, thanks for answering. I've tried your solution. For now, it is selecting automatically the current month in the picker when i click on it, but still I have to click on it, the data isn't displayed by default.

Comment: You can check my demo link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-htjuyr-datepicker